# how to change the youtube's privacyStatus from "unlisted" to "public"

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube

### My code snippet looks below:

```js
var resource = {
    "id": videoid,
    "status": {
      "privacyStatus": "public"
      
    }
  };
  YouTube.Videos.update(resource, 'id,status');
```

but I am getting this error "GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.videos.update failed with error: Forbidden
at updateStat(updateStat:30:18)"

I have checked the videoid and it looks good, and i can display all the video status with that videoid, and I can also manually changed the "privacyStatus" interactively on the web page, but not through this youtube api, and I did have the "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube" service in my project, is this some kind of permission issue that I have missed? appreciate any help?

I was just trying the change the privacyStatus from unlisted to public, and I am getting this "forbidden" error?